# Custom uiview with button inside alertController does not work in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uialertcontroller, uiswitch

I am trying to create an alert controller which has a custom view inside it. The custom view is loaded from xib file. The custom view contains a uiswitch. The problem is that its click event is not being triggered and from UI switch is not turned on/off on click. Here is the code I am trying to work on:

This is the button click event of my view controller to present alert:

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let customView=Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)!.first! as! CustomView
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("cancel")})
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        let somethingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Something", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in print("something")})
        alertController.addAction(somethingAction)

        alertController.view.addSubview(customView)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:{})
    }
```

This is the code inside CustomView class:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    @IBAction func switchClicked(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        print("switch cliked")
    }
}
```

My CustomView.xib file has the referencing layout properly set. It just has one uiswitch. The CustomView.xib has its size set to 'freeform'(not sure if it matters). I also tried setting *isUserInteractionEnabled* to false or true at various places for CustomView and/or alertController.view after searching for similar issues but nothing works.

Comment: When you add target to your UISwitch, did you select "valueChanged"?

Comment: Yes. I am capturing valueChanged event. It's not the problem with the uiswitch. The problem is with any type of button in general. Even if I put simple uibutton, its click method does not get triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You should be capturing the `valueChanged` control event but if you want to do the value change programmatically via click I suppose you could do:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    @IBAction func switchClicked(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        sender.setOn(!sender.isOn, animated: true)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I am capturing value changed. I've set referencing outlet to capture value change on UISwitch. Problem is its neither changing the switch from UI nor firing switchClicked event while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I think xib view will triger method only when same class has been loaded in memory. In your case this might be an issue . To test this u can add custom view in same class in which u are showing alert .